# reshaping array keras model to suit minimum size of pre_trained_model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to do some image classification using transfer learning on the inceptionv3 algorithm. I have 48x48 greyscale images but the inception v3 model needs a minimum input size of 75x5 (see below)

```
pre_trained_model = InceptionV3(input_shape = (48,48,3),
                           include_top  = False,
                           weights      = 'imagenet')

ValueError: Input size must be at least 75x75; Received: input_shape=(48, 48, 3)
```

If i try and reshape my array to something greater than 75x75 i get the following error which makes sense

```
train_images = train_image_array.reshape((train_image_array.shape[0], 76, 76, 1))
ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 66145536 into shape (28709,76,76,1)
```

How can i populate my array as something bigger than 75x75? I feel like it should be easy but i cant seem to find a solution. My code to populate my array is as follows:

```
image_array = np.zeros(shape=(len(data), 48, 48))
image_label = np.array(list(map(int, data['emotion'])))

for i, row in enumerate(data.index):
    image = np.fromstring(data.loc[row, 'pixels'], dtype=int, sep=' ')
    image = np.reshape(image, (48, 48))
    image_array[i] = image
    
return image_array, image_label
```

Comment: Reshape is not the same as resize, you want to resize the images, not reshape them.

Comment: @Dr. Snoopy If i resize my image with `image = np.resize(image, (150,150))` and then try and reshape `train_images = train_image_array.reshape((train_image_array.shape[0], 150, 150, 1))`

I still get the same error with the array size ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 66145536 into shape (28709,150,150,1)

Comment: Seems you resized only one image, not your whole dataset of images?

Answer (score 2):

As already pointed out, you just have to resize your with some kind of resizing method before feeding your dataset to the `Inception` model:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

model = tf.keras.applications.InceptionV3(input_shape = (75, 75, 3),
                           include_top = False,
                           weights = 'imagenet')
samples = 20
classes = 10
images = np.random.rand(samples, 48, 48, 3)
labels = np.random.randint(5, size=(samples, classes))
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((images, labels)).batch(5)

def resize_images(images, labels):
  return tf.image.resize(images, [75, 75], method=tf.image.ResizeMethod.NEAREST_NEIGHBOR), labels

dataset = dataset.map(resize_images)

for x, y in dataset:
  print(x.shape, y.shape)
```

```
(5, 75, 75, 3) (5, 10)
(5, 75, 75, 3) (5, 10)
(5, 75, 75, 3) (5, 10)
(5, 75, 75, 3) (5, 10)
```